# Who is the cat in chapter 17 of Prisoner of Azkaban?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, the name of chapter 17 is *Cat, Rat, and Dog*. Peter Pettigrew is the rat and Sirius Black is the dog (their respective Animagus forms). But who is the cat? Prof. McGonagall wasn't there, so it couldn't have been her in her cat Animagus form.

**Who is the cat in chapter 17 of *Prisoner of Azkaban***?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The cat was Hermione's half-Kneazle-half-cat, Crookshanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It was Crookshanks which had become friends with Sirius, the black dog. The title is for the animals involved in that book and how the cat helped the dog find the rat (ironical but true)